# Python unittest sudden quit

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a way to make python unittest (I am using 2.6, I have unittest2 available) as soon as an error or fail occured without waiting all tests to finish?

And a bonus question :) Is there a way to order tests. For example, pulling tests that are likely to fail on front?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `unittest` it with the `-f` option.

```
Options:
    -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
```

Example: `./auth_test.py -f`

Where at the end of `auth_test.py` you have

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

For ordering - I don't think so. At least not out of the box. You can, however, run only a single test or class.

```
./auth_test.py MyTestClass # will run all tests in MyTestClass
./auth_test.py MyTestClass.test_my_work # will run only the test_my_work test
```

Comment: I am really beginner at unittestig, so I am not familiar with command line usage. I am using it with unittest.main() call. Can you give an example usage?